# jQquery : add specific attr to each image

Tags: jquery, attributes

There is a loop (in my gallery script) that result me something like this :

```
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="uploads/rep2.png">
             <img src="uploads/rep2-150x110.png" class="thumbnail">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="uploads/rep1.png">
             <img src="uploads/rep1-150x110.png" class="thumbnail">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="uploads/rep2.png">
             <img src="uploads/rep2-150x110.png" class="thumbnail">
            </a>
        </div>
```

I want add specific attr (that is "href" of each link) to each image in this loop. Must be:

```
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="uploads/rep2.png">
             <img data-img="uploads/rep2.png" src="uploads/rep2-150x110.png" class="thumbnail">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="uploads/rep1.png">
             <img data-img="uploads/rep1.png" src="uploads/rep1-150x110.png" class="thumbnail">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="uploads/rep2.png">
             <img data-img="uploads/rep2.png" src="uploads/rep2-150x110.png" class="thumbnail">
            </a>
        </div>
```

I wrote this code:

```
$('.thumbnail').each(function() {
var $this = $('.gallery a'),
href = $this.data('href'); 
$('.thumbnail').attr('data-img', href);
        });
```

But not work.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close but you need to use `this` in each callback.

First take all the a tags in gallery, find their href, apply that to the img tag which is a child.

```
$('.gallery a').each(function() {
   href = $(this).attr('href');
   $(this).find("img").attr('data-img', href);
});
```

The key trick here is that `each()` sets the this variable to the element iterated over for each callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".gallery").each(function(index, value) {
    $("img", $(value)).attr("data-img", $("a", $(value)).attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

```
$('.thumbnail').each(function(i,n) {
var $this = $(n).parent(),
href = $this.data('href'); 
$('.thumbnail').attr('data-img', href);
});
```

`$('.gallery a')` => this simply gets all the a tags, and you probably end up with the same `href`

Answer (score 0):

[Attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) can take a function that will return the new value:

```
$('.thumbnail').attr("data-img", function() {
    return this.parentNode.getAttribute("href");
});
```

Comment: Probably only wants `.gallery .thumbnail`.

Answer (score 0):

`var $this = $('.gallery a');`

is returning an array (all of the `a` elements that are withing a `.gallery`). Try the following:

```
$('.gallery img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-img', $(this).parent().attr('href'));
});
```

This will go to each `img` and give it a data-img attribute with a value of its containing `a`'s `href`.

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the below comment, you probably only want the images in the gallery divs, so you should use the selector `$('.gallery img')` or `$('.gallery .thumbnail')` (if there are non-thumbnail images you want to skip).

Comment: Probably only wants `.gallery img`